# Giving parameter in Native sql in hibernate

Tags: sql, hibernate, parameters, native

Can someone please tell me how I can send parameter in native sql in hibernate
In the following code, i want to enter contract_id as a parameter.

```
  List list=session.createSQLQuery("select {b.*},{p.*},{t.*} from bidtool.bt_boiler_plates b,bidtool.bt_profile p,bidtool.bt_trade_lane t "
            + "where b.contract_id=p.contract_id AND p.contract_id=t.contract_id AND ")
                  .addEntity("b",Boiler_Plates.class)
                  .addEntity("p",BidToolProfiles.class)
                  .addEntity("t",BidToolTradeLanes.class).list();
```

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
List list=session.createSQLQuery("select {b.*},{p.*},{t.*} from bidtool.bt_boiler_plates b,bidtool.bt_profile p,bidtool.bt_trade_lane t "
            + "where b.contract_id=p.contract_id AND p.contract_id=t.contract_id AND contract_id=:contractId")
                  .addEntity("b",Boiler_Plates.class)
                  .addEntity("p",BidToolProfiles.class)
                  .addEntity("t",BidToolTradeLanes.class)
                  .setParameter("contractId", contractId).list();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this..

```
Query query = session.createSQLQuery("select {b.*},{p.*},{t.*} from bidtool.bt_boiler_plates b,bidtool.bt_profile p,bidtool.bt_trade_lane t "
        + "where b.contract_id=p.contract_id AND p.contract_id=t.contract_id AND contract_id=:ID")
              .addEntity("b",Boiler_Plates.class)
              .addEntity("p",BidToolProfiles.class)
              .addEntity("t",BidToolTradeLanes.class);

List list = query.setInteger("ID", 1234).list();
```

Comment: always favour named parameters over indexed ones, and you will have fewer bugs. Bugs in indexed parameters can be hard to debug.